# Rails 4, Poltergeist and Rspec, how to create or modify records from a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, poltergeist

I've this simple test:

```
it "test", js:true do
 fill_in "name", with: name
 fill_in "email", with: email
 fill_in "password", with: password
 fill_in "password_confirmation", with: password
 all(:xpath,'//input[@id="get-started-submit"]').first.click
 @runner = Runner.find_by email: email
 @runner.add_role :trainer
 visit '/admin'
end
```

If I put a debugger just after adding the role, all is fine the runner has a role. But when I visit "/admin" and go through the following controller the current runner doesn't have the role.

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :verify_admin

  private

  def verify_admin
    redirect_to root_url , notice: "You can't be here" unless current_runner.has_role? :trainer
  end
end
```

It seems that everything I do manually in the test is not persistent.

Any Idea ?

**EDIT:**

moving use_transactional_fixtures from true to false seems to fix the issue but not sure why .

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `@runner` is created successfully, try this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
. . .
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end


# Gemfile 
. . .
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

# spec/support/database_cleaner.rb
require "database_cleaner"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically if i need a user to be a certain role in an integration test, i create it prior to the test using something like factory girl. Your user setup steps are good for testing a registration, but when you want to test admin stuff, you're better off using something like factory girl, or the model itself to create your record.

That aside, are you sure the record is getting saved? I'm not sure what add_role does, but be sure that when you set or add a child to the runner instance, that you invoke save

Comment: Usually I create it before too and just log in with it but there was the same problem when I was trying the test with Poltergeist. The data was not persistent. But moving config.use_transactional_fixtures to false have fix my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ahh yes that would do it. Poltergeist runs on a separate process, so you have to use truncation. Keep that in mind if you implement database cleaner as well.